# How does the container networking handle the port mapping with .Net and Docker?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

When creating a new .Net 5 Web Api project you can find this in the generated **launchSettings.json** file

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
```

So when running the project you can call the Api endpoint via

> GET https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast

When adding Docker support for the project you might create a **Dockerfile** like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Api.dll" ]
```

Most sample files expose port 80 in that file. When running the Api in a Docker container via

```
docker run -p 8080:80 my-image
```

I have to change the call to

> GET http://localhost:8080/weatherforecast

So I call port 8080 which maps to port 80 internally but how does port 80 map to port 5000 to forward the request to the Api? It works "somehow". Would someone mind explaining this container networking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) say `launchSettings.json` file is used only for local development:

> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - contains profile settings.

As for docker image - it has environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` set to `http://+:80` so app listens to `80` port and there is no mapping happening between `80` and `5000`